# Java jsoup подгрузить страницу

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Часть страницы которую парсим скрыта. Что бы она подгрузилась надо кликнуть по блоку. Вот код этого блока

```
<div class="b-comments__next">
Ещё <span class="b-comments__next-count">1195</span> комментариев <i class="fa fa-refresh">::before</i> <span class="b-comments__next-error"></span>
                </div>
```

Какой команда jsoup нужна что бы он прокликивал по этому блоку после подгрузки страницы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы кликнуть что-либо на странице, необходимо использовать библиотеку [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). С помощью этой библиотеки Вы сможете кликнуть по блоку, далее достать **html-содержание** страницы и уже его распарсить **jsoup'ом**

Answer (score 3):

Такой команды нет. `Jsoup` предназначен только для парсинга HTML-данных, полученных после загрузки страницы/файла. Для выполнения `javascript` вам необходимо использовать [web-браузер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java). Однако если данные присутствуют на самой странице, но скрыты `css`-стилями, то их можно извлечь стандартными методами `Jsoup`.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой htmlunit. Бывает, если слишком много javascript, библиотека не справится, тогда берите Selenium.