# Не полностью парсится сайт

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть сайт, который пытаюсь парсить. Грубо говоря, **body** выглядит так:

```
<body>
  <div> ... </div>
  <div class="data"> ... </div>        <---Тот "див", с которым мне нужно работать
  <div> ... </div>
</body>
```

С помощью Jsoup получаю документ:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(address).get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

и проверяю что пришло. В body нет нужного для меня "дива". Остальные есть.

```
<body>
  <div> ... </div>
  //вот тут по идее должен лежать еще один див
  <div> ... </div>
</body>
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему так получается и как все таки достать этот "див"?

Comment: Возможно, див появляется после полной загрузки сайта посредством JavaScript или Jquery. Другого объяснения не вижу.

Comment: @Иван, в таком случае реально его достать?

Comment: К сожалению, не сталкивался с этим. Можете скинуть адрес и какой класс вы хотите вытащить, попробую решить вашу проблему? Если конечно не секрет.

Comment: @Иван, да, конечно, вот этот сайт: https://dapubg.com/#history/crash/all . Достать хочу все элементы класса game-coef. Буду очень Вам благодарен.

Comment: Сайт полностью написан на JS, т.е. подгружает динамически.    
  `Jsoup` не умеет запускать javascript. [Есть возможное решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481485/java-jsoup-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83)